# Upgrading Stripes application from jboss5 to jboss7

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, stripes

I have an App which Built in Stripes framework java and running on Jboss 5.
Now I upgrading this to run on Jboss 7.1 but after deploy on jboss 7 stripe unable to find action beans.

Could anyone please help me in calling Default handler of Stripes action beans.

Below is configuration in web.xml for `ActionResolver.Packages`

```
<filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.action</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Below is entry in stripes form for Action bean

```
<stripes:form acceptcharset="UTF-8"
        beanclass="com.action.LoginActionBean"
        id="stripes_login">
```

Below is entry of Default Handler method :-

```
public class LoginActionBean implements ActionBean {
    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution login() {
      /* code to login */
    }
}
```

And Getting bellow error :-

```
12:14:09,599 ERROR [net.sourceforge.stripes.tag.FormTag] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Could not locate an ActionBean that was bound to the URL [/Login.action]. Without an ActionBean class Stripes cannot determine whether the ActionBean is a wizard or not. As a result wizard behaviour will be disabled.
```

These all configuration is working correct in Jboss 5 but not in Jboss 7.1 Could anyone please let me know how can I get it running on Jb0ss 7.1?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I assume that LoginActionBean is in package `com.action` ?

Comment: yes correct LoginActionBean in com.action package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer for my question, I have to correct the data-source mapping as below for jboss 7.1:-
`<property name="connection.datasource">java:jboss/datasources/eagle</property>`
For Jboss 5 it was :-
`<property name="connection.datasource">java:eagle</property>` in hibernate.cfg.xml file. Means the database name must be written same in both standalone.xml and hibernate config file.

Hope this help someone!